# Бот не выдаёт роли по кнопкам

Tags: python, discord.py, disnake

```
@bot.slash_command(name="verify", description='Verifycation user')
async def buttons(inter: disnake.ApplicationCommandInteraction, member: disnake.Member):
    
    embed=disnake.Embed(
        title="Verifycation user",
        description=f"Verify user {member.mention}",
        color=0x00ff00
    )
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar.url)
    await inter.response.send_message(embed=embed,
        components=[
            disnake.ui.Button(label="Boy", style=disnake.ButtonStyle.grey, custom_id="boy"),
            disnake.ui.Button(label="Girl", style=disnake.ButtonStyle.gray, custom_id="girl"),
            disnake.ui.Button(label="No entry", style=disnake.ButtonStyle.gray, custom_id="no_entry")
        ], ephemeral= True
    )

    def callback(inter: disnake.MessageInteraction):
        if inter.component.custom_id == "boy":
            role = disnake.utils.get(guild_id=member.guild.id, role_id=role)
            member.add_roles(role)
            inter.response.send_message("text", ephemeral= True)

        elif inter.component.custom_id == "girl":
            role = disnake.utils.get(guild_id=member.guild.id, role_id=role)
            member.add_roles(role)
            inter.response.send_message("text", ephemeral= True)

        elif inter.component.custom_id == "no_entry":
            role = disnake.utils.get(guild_id=member.guild.id, role_id=role)        
            member.add_roles(role)
            inter.response.send_message("text", ephemeral= True)
```

Хочу, чтобы саппорты с помощью команды выдавали гендерные роли `disnake.Member` нажимая на кнопки

Comment: вместо создания [дубликата](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1539094/%d0%9f%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bb-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf) стоило внести правки в уже существующий вопрос.

Comment: Это не правки, это просто чтобы быстрее заметили )

Answer (score 0):

Я на ваш вопрос не отвечу, но предложу вариант при котором автор сообщения сможет сам выбрать роль:

```
@bot.slash_command(name='verify', description='Verifycation user')
async def buttons(inter: disnake.ApplicationCommandInteraction, member: disnake.Member):

    embed = disnake.Embed(
        title='Verifycation user',
        description=f'Verify user {member.mention}',
        color=0x00ff00
    )
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar.url)
    await inter.response.send_message(
        embed=embed,
        components=[
            disnake.ui.Button(label='Boy', style=disnake.ButtonStyle.gray, custom_id='boy'),
            disnake.ui.Button(label='Girl', style=disnake.ButtonStyle.gray, custom_id='girl'),
            disnake.ui.Button(label='No entry', style=disnake.ButtonStyle.gray, custom_id='no_entry')
        ],
        ephemeral=True
    )

@bot.listen('on_button_click')
async def callback(inter: disnake.MessageInteraction):
    if inter.component.custom_id not in ['boy', 'girl', 'no_entry']:
        return

    if inter.component.custom_id == 'boy':
        roleBoy = inter.guild.get_role(1148364761260626000)
        if roleBoy in inter.user.roles:
            await inter.user.remove_roles(roleBoy)
            await inter.response.send_message('Вы сняли с себя роль `Boy`', ephemeral=True)
        else:
            await inter.user.add_roles(roleBoy)
            await inter.response.send_message('Вы получили роль `Boy`', ephemeral=True)

    elif inter.component.custom_id == 'girl':
        roleGirl = inter.guild.get_role(1148364834006634536)
        if roleGirl in inter.user.roles:
            await inter.user.remove_roles(roleGirl)
            await inter.response.send_message('Вы сняли с себя роль `Girl`', ephemeral=True)
        else:
            await inter.user.add_roles(roleGirl)
            await inter.response.send_message('Вы получили роль `Girl`', ephemeral=True)

    elif inter.component.custom_id == 'no_entry':
        roleNoEntry = inter.guild.get_role(1148364856098046025)
        if roleNoEntry in inter.user.roles:
            await inter.user.remove_roles(roleNoEntry)
            await inter.response.send_message('Вы сняли с себя роль `No entry`', ephemeral=True)
        else:
            await inter.user.add_roles(roleNoEntry)
            await inter.response.send_message('Вы получили роль `No entry`', ephemeral=True)
```

Только вам нужно указать **ID ролей** из вашего сервера, на примере выше был указан **ID ролей** из моего сервера:

```
roleBoy = inter.guild.get_role(АЙДИ ВАШЕЙ РОЛИ)
roleGirl = inter.guild.get_role(АЙДИ ВАШЕЙ РОЛИ)
roleNoEntry = inter.guild.get_role(АЙДИ ВАШЕЙ РОЛИ)
```

Найти можно в `Настройки сервера` > `Роли` > `[Выбираете нужную роль]` > `Ещё (троеточие в углу)` > `Копировать ID роли`

Если такой кнопки нету, то зайдите в `Настройки пользователя` > `Расширенные` > `Режим разработчика` и повторите предыдущее действие.

Comment: Это не то, что нужно, но спасибо

Comment: @Hosako Да, но хочу уточнить, вы хотите чтобы модераторы могли выдавать роли любому участнику просто нажимая кнопки?

Comment: Именно упомянутому человеку через `disnake.member`.
Я хочу что бы модератору выдавал роль упомянутому человеку.